# OpenCV contours not displaying

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a basic image of a sudoku board and am trying to draw the contour around the edge of the image but cannot manage to get any of the contours to appear. My code looks as follows:

```
    threshold(img_grey, img_thresh, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    std::vector<std::vector<Point>> contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

    cv::findContours(img_thresh, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    Scalar color(0, 255, 0);
    drawContours( img_thresh, contours, -1, color, 3, hierarchy);

    namedWindow( "Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Image", img_thresh);

    waitKey( 0 );
    destroyWindow( "Image" );
```

Any help is much appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From the OpenCV documentation (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html), the arguments in your call are out of order. `hierarchy` should come after `lineType`.

```
drawContours( img_thresh, contours, -1, color, 3, hierarchy);
```

Should be

```
    drawContours( img_thresh, contours, -1, color, 3,  LINE_8, hierarchy, 0);
```

See also:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc

Comment: D'oh! I will edit this. The arguments are most definitely not correct.

Comment: The contour appears when drawing it on a black canvas like in the second documentation link. However, it does not appear when I try to apply it on img_thresh, not sure if there is a hierarchy among pixels I am unaware of.